# How can I use the original unicode characters for the four card suits in a jupyter notebook?

Tags: unicode, jupyter-notebook

If I copy and paste the four symbols from the character selection panel (I'm on macOS) they change to the following: ♠️ ♣️ ♥️ ♦️, whereas I'd like the heart and diamond to be red.

EDIT: Interestingly, i've noticed that if I type the sequence ‍♥️, and then I hit backspace when the cursor is *between* those two characters, they both transform into ‍♥️! (the same happens with the other three)
Can someone explain what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because your browser doesn't know about these special characters. But I think you can check this page https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp
and replace special characters with unicode codes from page

or from this page http://graphemica.com/%E2%9D%A4

Comment: Ha. I just opened this page with safari 11.1.1 and my post looks different (I wrote it with Firefox 60.0.2).